# fields_for in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, fields-for

When I attempt to use fields_for in the view code below, the company_name is not showing up in the view.  What am I doing wrong?

```
= form_for @company do |f|
  -if @company.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this company from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @company.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  =f.fields_for :showing do |t|
    .field
      = t.label :company_name
      = t.text_field :company_name
  .field
    = f.label :geography
    = f.text_area :geography
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not building a `showing` object in your controller?

```
@company.build_showing
```

If you've defined `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on your `Company` model, then you'll need to set up the nested objects in the controller as well as the parent objects.